# Where do I handle custom authentication and authorization in webapi?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorization

NOTE: I have many questions littered in the code comments below. I need answers to those as well.

I have read (among many others) the following articles:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig1/archive/2012/05/11/how-to-write-a-custom-parameter-binding-to-construct-an-object-either-from-body-or-from-uri-s-query.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx

I would like for my web api to have authentication sent in the header using the Authorization header. I would like this header to be populated into a c# class called `AuthenticationToken`. Then when I am doing parameter binding I would like to retreive this previously created `AuthenticationToken` object and pass it on to my controller action. For example, if I have the following controller

```
public class MyServiceController : ApiController {

    readonly ISecurityService _security;
    readonly IMyService _myService;

    // constructor values are injected
    public MyServiceController(ISecurityService security, IMyService myService) {
        _security = security;
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public SomeData GetASpecificItem(AuthenticationToken token, int id) {

       if (_security.IsAuthorized(token, Permissions.Read)) {
           return myService.DoStuffToGetSomeData(token);
       } else {
          var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
          throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
       }
    }
}
```

and the following parameter binding class

```
public class AuthenticationTokenParameterBinding 
  : HttpParameterBinding { // do I need to inherit from a different class?

  public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
                                           HttpActionContext actionContext,
                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    try {

      AuthenticationToken token; // UPDATED: how can i get this from the data 
                                 //          available from inside this method?

      SetValue(actionContext, token);

      // is this the correct task to return on successfull parameter binding?
      return base.ExecuteBindingAsyn(metadataProvider, actionContext, cancellationToken);

    } catch {
      return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        var hpm = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        hpm.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate","MyCustomScheme");
        return hpm;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If these two are implemented correctly, then the controller will automatically get the `AuthenticationToken` instance that was created during authorization.

I do not know where to authenticate ahead of this process. Nor do I know how to pass an object between authentication and authorization.

**UPDATE:**
I can't use a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` because authorization may be against an object:

```
public SaveResponse Save(AuthenticationToken user, SomeObjectThatNeedsToBeSaved obj) {

  // NOTE: permissions are checked between the object and the user, not a role

  if (_security.IsAuthorized(user, obj, Permission.Modify, Permission.Create)) {

     // NOTE: other permissions we don't know about may need to be checked in the service call

     return new SaveResponse {
         Success = ISomeService.Save(user, obj); // bool return value
     }
  } else {
     // return 403 Forbidden      }
}
```

I need to pass the token to the controller action, but I also need to authenticate the token before it gets passed to the controller. Since all of this is not necessarily role based, I don't see how I can authenticate from inside of a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

I have used a custom **AuthorizeAttribute** to handle both authentication and authorization for Web API.  This attribute works as a filter and will process the request before it gets to your Web API method.  In the overridden **OnAuthorize** method you can return **HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)** if authentication fails and **HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)** if authorization fails so that the client can distinguish between both types of errors. In addition to the custom **AuthorizeAttribute** I implemented a custom **MembershipProvider** and **RoleProvider** to handle my specific security requirements and custom database schema.

I use basic authentication to pass the credentials for authorization. This puts the credentials in the header. To do this is pretty straight forward by using the **beforeSend** event handler of the JQuery **ajax** function. Here is an example of how to do this.

```
    getAuthorizationHeader = function (username, password) {
      var authType;
      var up = $.base64.encode(username + ":" + password);
      authType = "Basic " + up;
    };
    return authType;
 };

    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        type: _type,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getAuthorizationHeader(username, password));
        },
        success: ajaxSuccessHandler,
        error: ajaxErrHandler
    });
```

This encodes the username/password that is sent in the header. Note that this is not enough security to rely on just the encoding as it is easy to decode. You still want to use HTTPS/SSL to make sure the information sent over the wire is secure.

On the Web API side you can make a custom **AuthorizeAttribute** that gets the credentials from the header, decodes them, and performs your authorization process. There is a separate **AuthorizeAttribute** used by the Web API as opposed to the controller.  Be sure to use **System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute** as your base class when creating your custom **AuthorizeAttribute**.   They have different behaviors. The one for the controller will want to redirect to the logon page whereas the one for the Web API returns an HTTP code indicating success or failure. I return an HTTP code of Forbidden if authorization fails to distinguish a failure due to authorization as opposed to authentication so the client can react accordingly.

Here is an example method for getting the credentials from the header that can be used in the custom **AuthorizeAttribute**.

```
    private bool GetUserNameAndPassword(HttpActionContext actionContext, out string username, out string password)
    {
        bool gotIt = false;
        username = string.Empty;
        password = string.Empty;
        IEnumerable<string> headerVals;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out headerVals))
        {
            try
            {
                string authHeader = headerVals.FirstOrDefault();
                char[] delims = { ' ' };
                string[] authHeaderTokens = authHeader.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                if (authHeaderTokens[0].Contains("Basic"))
                {
                    string decodedStr = SecurityHelper.DecodeFrom64(authHeaderTokens[1]);
                    string[] unpw = decodedStr.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    username = unpw[0];
                    password = unpw[1];
                }
                gotIt = true;
            }
            catch { gotIt = false; }
        }

        return gotIt;
    }
```

And here is the code for decoding the header data that is used in this method.

```
    public static string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
    {

        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes

            = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);

        string returnValue =

           System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);

        return returnValue;

    }
```

Once you have the username and password you can perform your authorization process and return the appropriate HTTP code to the client for handling.

You could perform the a similar process with your custom token, or you can leverage the cookie that is passed back and forth if you do not want to keep the password/username stored in the client.

Comment: I can't use role based security. This method won't work. That is why I'm trying to do it the way I presented in my question.

Comment: This method does not preclude authorization methods other than role-based. If you are not using roles what are you authorizing on?

Comment: against objects, e.g. does this user have modify permissions on xyz object. Also, my question is about authentication, not authorization. Authorization is done in the code. That is why I need the authentication token in the method signature.

Comment: I assumed both because of the title of the question. You can just handle authentication in the same manor as I have described. And you can change it to send over a token instead of the encoded username/password. Sorry, I just do not get what you are trying to do with the token in the method signature.